# Unable to load class warning messages with glassfish3.1.2, primefaces 3.4, maven

Tags: maven, logging, primefaces, glassfish

[Maven : Strange ClassNotFoundException of Primefaces library on deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954487/maven-strange-classnotfoundexception-of-primefaces-library-on-deploy)

Hi there everyone!

The link above mostly describes my problem, but since it is not solved I'm a bit stucked with this. So the problem is the vast number of warning messages, which appear when I'm deploying the application. I'm using **Glassfish 3.1.2**, **Maven 2.2.1** and **Primefaces 3.4**. Like in the post mentioned, there is no problem with the functionality of the application, so this does not affects anything besides my nerves :) I think these messages are totally unnecessary and I would REALLY like to get rid of them.

Below is *pom.xml* where the primefaces dependencies are loaded:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hu.mps.invito</groupId>
        <artifactId>invito-ejbs</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>ui-lightness</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As a workaround, I tried setting log levels for any jsf components in the glassfish admin console, but with no luck.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution (or workaround) for this issue. You have to set the *javax.enterprise.system.container.web* logger in Glassfish to SEVERE level, this way the warnings does not appear.